# SecurityContextHolder returns null using custom LogoutHandler

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-boot-security

The use case is to store the user name/id in a database, when logging out. When trying to retrieve the username from the context, I will receive always null.

In Debug mode I evaluated this line in CustomLogoutHandler via my IDE (not in the code of `CustomLogoutHandler`) and it's null.
`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();`

```java
@Service
public class CustomLogoutHandler implements LogoutHandler {

    private final AuditorService auditorService;

    public CustomLogoutHandler(AuditorService auditorService) {
        this.auditorService = auditorService;
    }

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication) {
        auditorService.addLogoutActivity(ActivityEnum.LOGOUT, null, authentication.getName()); 
        // authentication object is null
    }
}
```

The `SecurityConfiguration` class

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;
    private final TokenProvider tokenProvider;
    private final CorsFilter corsFilter;
    private final SecurityProblemSupport problemSupport;
    private final DomainUserDetailsService domainUserDetailsService;
    private final ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

    private final CustomLogoutHandler customLogoutHandler;

// constructor omitted

  @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
            .antMatchers("/app/**/*.{js,html}")
            .antMatchers("/i18n/**")
            .antMatchers("/content/**")
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**")
            .antMatchers("/test/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
            .logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutUrl("/api/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .addLogoutHandler(customLogoutHandler)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new HttpStatusReturningLogoutSuccessHandler(HttpStatus.OK))
            )
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(problemSupport)
            .accessDeniedHandler(problemSupport)
            .and()
            .headers()
            .contentSecurityPolicy(jHipsterProperties.getSecurity().getContentSecurityPolicy())
            .and()
            .referrerPolicy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN)
            .and()
            .permissionsPolicy().policy("camera=(), fullscreen=(self), geolocation=(), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), midi=(), payment=(), sync-xhr=()")
            .and()
            .frameOptions()
            .deny()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/logout").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/init").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/account/reset-password/finish").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/websocket/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/health/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .antMatchers("/audit/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.AUDITOR)
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());
        // @formatter:on
    }

    // stuff omitted
}
```

I don't know where the context and the user name/id gets consumed in the sense of destroyed, before I can catch him/her, who issued the logout event and store it to the DB.

- Is it because something else behind the scenes destroys the `Authentication` contents?
  I once had the issue, when two `ApplicationListener<SessionDisconnectEvent>` classes were listening to a disconnect. The first consumed the event and the SecurityContextHolder returned the user's name and did it's work and the second class with its `onApplicationEvent(SessionDisconnectEvent event)` couldn't work because `SecurityContextHolder` was null or empty (don't remember exactly). It seems, that `SecurityContextHolder` can only be used once for the identical event. Forgive me, but I don't understand Spring behind the curtains completely.
- Shall I setup a "/custom_logout" as another endpoint and then internally navigate to spring's "/logout" endpoint, when the use case, described initially, is completed?